# Angular 15 - Lazy loaded nested child component route loads parent component

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-evaluation

Angular 15 project. All of my components are standalone, and I have no App.Module. At the moment all my routes are configured and bootstrapped in my main.ts.

Given the following working scenario.

**/dashboard** > Redirects to /dashboard/games

**/dashboard/games** > Loads the *GamesComponent*

I am trying to implement the following path,

**/dashboard/games/game/123** > Loads the *GameComponent*

In my routing, games is a child route of dashboard. And game is a child route of games.

However, when I try to load path **/dashboard/games/game/123** it loads the *GamesComponent*

Here is the relevant part of my routing,

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.component').then((m) => m.UserDashboardComponent),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'games',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'games',
        loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/games.component').then((m) => m.GamesComponent),
        children: [
          {
            path: 'game/:id',
            loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/game/game.component').then((m) => m.GameComponent)
          }
        ]
      }
]
}};

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
      importProvidersFrom(RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }))
    ]
  })
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here?

If I remove route **game/:id** from being a child of games, and add it at the same level converting to **games/game/:id** then it works. So why would this child route not work?

Comment: I created a [demo repository](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/angular-page-routing) that shows how/why it works this way. If you remove `component: xxxComponent` from your route and the `<router-outlet>` from your parent page, then angular will only show the nested component [Commit reference](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/angular-page-routing/commit/a6e9d23172636ac3e44fb287a62da0b574578128)

Comment: Thanks @Pieterjan for your efforts. I can see how it scales in your example. I think my issue is that all my components are standalone and I have no modules. So I need to find another way of activating those routes.

Comment: Ok @Pieterjan, I've reproduced your project with standalone components here [angular standalone routing](https://github.com/insinfinity/angular-standalone-routing/tree/main/src). It's all working perfectly.

I've got a similar setup with my own project now with the routes being loaded using loadChildren but there must still be something missing so I'll go back over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an unfortunate expected behaviour...

Doing this is invalid for a lazzy loaded component, as you are trying to define route children of a component that is not yet loaded:

```
{
 path: 'games',
 loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/games.component').then((m) => m.GamesComponent),
 children: [
  {
   path: 'game/:id',
   loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/game/game.component').then((m) => m.GameComponent)
  }
 ]
}
```

to make it work, you need to define the 'games' route children inside the component from `app/user-dashboard/games/games.component`;

Or as you figured, reconfigure the route as:

```
{
 path: 'games',
 loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/games.component').then((m) => m.GamesComponent),
},
{
 path: 'games/game/:id',
 loadComponent: () => import('./app/user-dashboard/games/game/game.component').then((m) => m.GameComponent)
}
```

Comment: This is not how I was expecting it to work at all. I thought that the configuration defined would sit in a route table which would be read at runtime, and the lazy loading would occur as the route was matched. If it works as you say, they it would be very limited. I had hoped to split out my route table using load children. Do you know if its something that's been improved in later versions?

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I think this has given me enough of a nudge in the right direction. I have managed to reproduce the child route loading with standalone components (angular standalone routing)[https://github.com/insinfinity/angular-standalone-routing/tree/main/src] so I know it works. I will look at my other project and find what's missing.